# Is it possible to restore only tables/constraints from database backup?

Tags: c#, sql-server

For circumstances beyond my control (permissions/bureaucracy), I'm unable to use SSIS or Scheduler Agent to create an automated, scheduled production database backup and development database restore.  Instead, I'm attempting to use C#.NET to create a .exe file that will perform the backup/recovery.  Please correct me if I'm going about this in the wrong direction or there are better alternatives.

I haven't tested any of the following yet, so they're just concepts for now.

First, I'm backing up the production database using the following function:

```
private static void BackupProductionDatabase()
{
    string backupFileName = "ProdBackup-" + 
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".bak";
    DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(AppSettings.ProdConnectionString);
    string sql = "BACKUP DATABASE [USPRD1828] TO DISK = " +
                 "'" + AppSettings.BackupDirectory + backupFileName + "'";
    dh.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
}
```

Then, I have a stored procedure with a slightly modified version of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473313/1077685) to drop only primary/foreign key constraints and tables on the development database.  The views and stored procedures will remain intact.

Provided that I have a `.bak` copy of the production database from the above code snippet, is it possible to restore ONLY the primary/foreign key constraints and tables from the production backup to the development database using either (or both) TSQL/C#.NET?

Comment: Chek the `Red Gate`'s SQL Compare(http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) - the bundle has 14 days free period.

Comment: NO, you cannot extract only bits and pieces from a `.bak` backup file - the restore is an all-or-nothing process. You *could* restore to a temporary staging database, and then just fetch those bits and pieces you need